# Print in Modal View for SPS2013 List does prints blank page apart from content

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, modal-dialog, printing

Print in modal view, prints blank pages too

I have added a HTML code to enable print in modal view for SharePoint 2013 Lists.
Print command works and give you the option to print.
However all the time print will print 1st page as blank and last page too as blank.

I have 2 content editor on the dispform.aspx, which is been used by modal view.

Wondering what can i do to allow only the content to be printed.

Comment: @Ahmed, any suggestions

Comment: Jason, do you have the code you tried? I'm facing a similar issue. If you use Google Chrome, I read in Stack Overflow that the preview print is actually a image, so, if you're trying print using Chrome, this may be the reason you have blank pages.